# Redirect 404 pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Few weeks back I made changes to my wordpress site ctageory slug redirecting `https://example.com/category/catname/` to `https://example.com/catname/` to strip the 'category' base slug. Due to some restraints again I changed it back to normal as `https://example.com/category/catname/`

Now I am having number of 404 category archive pages crawl errors in Google Webmaster Tools, the errors like below:

```
1. https://example.com/catname/page/1/?
2. https://example.com/catname/page/2/?
```

How can I redirect these /catname/page/(.*) to /category/catname/page/$1. I have tried redirecting with htaccess and wordpress redirect plugins but nothing seemed to be working and resultedmost browsers saying "too many redirects" and the page didn't load.

I have been struggling with it. Any help shall be appreciable.
Thank you very much